# All Visual Studio 2010 vcprojects fail with no error code

Tags: visual-studio-2010, build

Has anyone experienced this? All of the sudden all of my C/C++ projects are failing to build with no error codes displayed. I haven't installed any new software recently. My C-Sharp projects are still building fine.

Any suggestions?  Thanks.

Comment: How do you know they're failing to build? Can you copy the build output from the Output Window, and paste it into your question using the [edit] link?

Answer (score 1):

I found out the reason, in case anyone else runs into the same problem. It was the VMWare Integrated Debugger. I disabled that and now my projects build ok.